# Intepreting Martingale Notation

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I'm having trouble interepreting the following notation on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Martingale_sequences_with_respect_to_another_sequence) for martingales:

$$\mathbf{E} ( Y_{t} \mid \{ X_{\tau}, \tau \leq s \} ) = Y_s\quad \forall s \le t$$

The stopping time of the conidtioning variable is $\tau$. If the process $(X_t)$ stops at $\tau$, shouldn't we have the following instead? --
$$\mathbf{E} ( Y_{t} \mid \{ X_{\tau}, \tau \leq s \} ) = Y_{\tau}\quad \forall s \le t$$

Comment: This notation is a bit confusing. Generally $\tau$ is used to denote a stopping time, but here it is instead used as a dummy variable in defining the natural filtration generated by $\{X_t\}$. To be more clear, for $s\geqslant 0$ let
$$
\mathcal F_s = \sigma(\{X_u : u\leqslant s\}).
$$
Then an integrable process $\{Y_t\}$ is a martingale with respect to $\{\mathcal F_s\}$ if for all $0\leqslant s\leqslant t$, 
$$
\mathbb E[Y_t\mid \mathcal F_s] = Y_s.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Note that $\tau$ is **not** a stopping time, it is just an arbitrary real number less than or equal to $s$.

In particular, this property is the same as saying that for all $s \le t$,

$$ \mathbb E [Y_t \vert \{X_u,u\le s \}] = Y_s. $$

The conditioning means that our information is generated by the path of the process $X$ up to time $s$. (Compare this with the definition of the property in discrete time.)